# How can I install custom CA certificate to Sonoff NSPanel Pro?

Tags: home-assistant, android, sonoff

I have installed a Home Assistant to Sonoff NSPanel Pro according to this guide:

https://blakadder.com/android-panel-webview/

finally I installed the Home Assistant.

When I tried to connect to my home assistant I get a certificate error due to my local home assistant uses my own CA in local area network.

I have tried to add my own CA certificate to android

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46569793/5728926

but it seems to me that not works. Home assistant shows a certificate error and I cannot ignore it.

How can I add my own CA certificate to Sonoff NS Panel Pro?